# "apt purge libglib2.0-dev" fails

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

I am having the error below occur.  I don't know what option exists when `apt purge` fails.

```
$ sudo apt purge libglib2.0-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libpcre3-dev libpcre32-3 libpcrecpp0v5
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libglib2.0-dev*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 9,050 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 265187 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing libglib2.0-dev (2.48.2-0ubuntu1) ...
  File "/usr/bin/pyclean", line 63
    except (IOError, OSError), e:
                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
dpkg: error processing package libglib2.0-dev (--purge):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libglib2.0-dev
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Hmm... isn't that a classic python2 versus python3 symptom? Have you installed any non-default python version(s)?

Comment: maybe firstly you should install configparser by `pip install configparser` , and then purge it.